# How does a Resplendent Mansion scale with level exactly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, area-of-effect

The [Resplendent Mansion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resplendent-mansion/) spell has this effect:

> **Effect:** opulent mansion, up to 300 feet on a side and one story tall/4 levels

For a lv 20 caster, is this mansion:

1. 1500 x 1500 feet with 5 stories tall?
2. 300 x 300 feet with 5 stories tall?

Comment: An interesting aside, it also doesn't mention any limit on shape or how many sides it has, only that each side is 300 feet. If you made it into a decagon instead of a square for example it would go from 90 thousand square feet to just under 700 thousand square feet per floor.

Comment: And that's why there are GM's

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any developer's insight to this, so all I have is my personal reading of the spell. I would say it is **300ft x300ft x5 stories** due to the first line of the spell description:

> This spell creates a towering mansion.

While I know that 5 stories is 5 stories, a tall thin building is more likely to be described as 'towering' than something that spans 1500ft (more than a quarter mile) on a side.

As always, the GM for each specific game has the final say in its arbitration. Maybe this will get FAQ'd on Paizo's forum to give GM's a little bit better idea of the spell's intent.

Comment: Developer insight is not required in this particular case, although always welcome. Thanks for your input.